# Error 1140 in my query

Tags: mysql

```
select country.continent,round(avg(city.population),0) as c 
from city,country 
where city.countrycode = country.code;
```

I have used this query but I'm getting this error

> ERROR 1140 (42000) at line 1: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'run_2sryibds0p4.country.continent'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

help me with correct solution and explanation please.

Comment: [Read the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: a little help with the correct query please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the aggregate `AVG` only by using the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT country.continent, ROUND(AVG(city.population), 0) AS c 
FROM city,country 
WHERE city.countrycode = country.code
GROUP BY country.continent;
```

More information about `GROUP BY` and the aggregate functions (like `AVG`):

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT country.continent,round(avg(city.population),0) as c 
FROM city.country 
WHERE city.countrycode = country.code
GROUP BY 1
```

The aggregated columns need to be grouped by the non aggregated columns - in this case the rounded average of population should be grouped by `country.continent`.

Look here for more information 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html